# Electron packaged app error: document is not defined

Tags: webpack, electron

My app runs perfectly with react, webpack and electron in development mode but whenever I package my app with electron-build and try to run the installed app, I get this error:
[image: ReferenceError: document is not defined]

I've tried everything I could find online but no luck. Here is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "contego-investigative-services",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config=webpack.common.js",
    "package": "electron-builder build --win -c.extraMetadata.main=build/app.bundle.js --publish never",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "watch": "webpack --config webpack.common.js --watch",
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "build": {
    "productName": "CONTENGO Investigative Services",
    "appId": "CONTENGO Investigative Services",
    "win": {
      "target": [
        "nsis"
      ],
      "icon": "icon.ico"
    },
    "nsis": {
      "oneClick": false,
      "installerIcon": "icon.ico",
      "uninstallerIcon": "icon.ico",
      "uninstallDisplayName": "Uninstall CONTENGO Investigative Services",
      "license": "license.md",
      "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true
    },
    "files": [
      "build/**/*",
      "node_modules/**/*"
    ],
    "asarUnpack": [
      "node_modules/ffmpeg-static/bin/${os}/${arch}/ffmpeg",
      "node_modules/ffmpeg-static/index.js",
      "node_modules/ffmpeg-static/package.json"
    ]
  },
  "engine": {
    "node": "v18.7.0"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/davidchavezTech/trackops-rebuild.git"
  },
  "author": "David Chavez Tech",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/davidchavezTech/trackops-rebuild/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/davidchavezTech/trackops-rebuild#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.1.3",
    "caniuse-lite": "^1.0.30001451",
    "ffmpeg-static": "^5.1.0",
    "ffprobe-static": "^3.1.0",
    "fluent-ffmpeg": "^2.1.2",
    "latest": "^0.2.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.10",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "electron": "^20.0.1",
    "electron-build": "^0.0.3",
    "electron-reload": "^2.0.0-alpha.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "sass": "^1.54.3",
    "sass-loader": "^13.0.2",
    "styles-loader": "^4.0.1",
    "webpack": "^5.74.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to remove part of the `package` script from this `"package": "electron-builder build --win -c.extraMetadata.main=build/app.bundle.js --publish never",` to `"package": "electron-builder build --win --publish never",`

`-c.extraMetadata.main=build/app.bundle.js` was in the tutorial that I was following and it's what was causing the problem.